# Enabling visually italicizing characters in \emph when using LaTeX-Suite

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I am using Vim + LaTeX-Suite plugin to write LaTeX source file. I noticed that LaTeX-Suite would automatically italicize characters in `\textit`.

[image: Text inside <code>\textit</code> get visually italicized]

Is there a way to enable this behavior for `\emph` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, unlike `\textit`, `\emph` acts as a switch to indicate emphasis. So when used in regular text `\emph` is by default defined as italics, but within already emphasized text `\emph` switches back to upright. Therefore it is not fully semantically correct to highlight `\emph` as italics in the editor.

However, it can be done without too much trouble. The highlighting comes from Vim itself, not from Latex-Suite. The syntax highlighting definitions are stored in a directory similar to `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax` (the exact location can be different depending on your installation method and version). In the file `tex.vim` the highlighting for LaTeX is defined. Vim can read additional highlighting definitions from files placed in `~/.vim/after/syntax`. So you can copy the relevant definitions for `\textit` from the original `tex.vim` files, substitute `\emph` and save this as an additional file in the `/after/syntax` directory.

In the following file the first two blocks are copied from the original `tex.vim` to define the variables `tex_fast` and `tex_conceal`, the third block contains the actual definitions for `\emph`. Note that I did not implement bold+emphasized combinations.

`~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`:

```
" by default, enable all region-based highlighting
let s:tex_fast= "bcmMprsSvV"
if exists("g:tex_fast")
 if type(g:tex_fast) != 1
  " g:tex_fast exists and is not a string, so
  " turn off all optional region-based highighting
  let s:tex_fast= ""
 else
  let s:tex_fast= g:tex_fast
 endif
endif

" let user determine which classes of concealment will be supported
"   a=accents/ligatures d=delimiters m=math symbols  g=Greek  s=superscripts/subscripts
if !exists("g:tex_conceal")
 let s:tex_conceal= 'abdmgsS'
else
 let s:tex_conceal= g:tex_conceal
endif

" particular support for emph {{{1
if s:tex_fast =~# 'b'
  if s:tex_conceal =~# 'b'
   if !exists("g:tex_nospell") || !g:tex_nospell
    syn region texItalStyle matchgroup=texTypeStyle start="\\emph\s*{" matchgroup=texTypeStyle  end="}" concealends contains=@texItalGroup,@Spell
   else                                                                                              
    syn region texItalStyle matchgroup=texTypeStyle start="\\emph\s*{" matchgroup=texTypeStyle  end="}" concealends contains=@texItalGroup
   endif
  endif
endif
```

Screenshot from Vim:

[image]